# Auto parse price with money-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, money-rails

I have implemented the money-rails gem to enables prices on an `Item` model.

Right now I parse a `string` with the price before creating a new `Item` in the `items_controller.rb`, like this:

```
@item = Item.find_or_create_by_link!(params[:item][:link]) do |c|
    c.assign_attributes(params[:item])
    c.price = params[:item][:price].to_money unless params[:item][:price].nil?
end
```

However, I was wondering if there is a more 'correct' way of automatically parsing the string before saving it to the model. I was trying a `before_save` filter but couldn't get it to work.

The price is stored in two columns in the `Item` model, `price_cents` and `price_currency`.

Answer (score 1):

You could override the attribute writer in your `Item` model or even define a new instance method (as a virtual attribute) that performs all related logic. For example:

`models/item.rb`

```
...
def price=(price)
  money = price.to_money
  self.price_cents = money.fractional
  self.price_currency = money.currency.iso_code
end
```